# Storing and replacing Json Data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some Json Data I am getting from an API, I want to store it for later use, in case the user has no Internet connection. But I am not sure what my best option is to save it.
I was thinking about using `sqflite`, but in my use case I will need to fully replace all entries, so I would have to delete and rewrite about 300 `columns`, split between 5 tables, pretty regularly and I am not sure if that is ideal.

I also considered just saving the Json file to device storage or even using shared preferences.

Do any of you have experience/ideas on what my best option would be? Will `sqflite` be slow if I use it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `sqflite` would be the best option when it comes to persisting data if you want to create an offline cache for the user.

Using shared preferences would be slower as NSUserDefaults and its Android counterpart are not designed for high performance read/write operations therefore any insert, update and query operations would be slower in general if you handle big amounts of data.

Saving the Json file to device storage would be in my opinion the lest performant option if you have to query it afterwards as you would have to serialise/deserialise whereas if you use the database you'll be able to quickly query data and instantiate your on model objects etc. I'd recommend you to follow a layered approach if possible (using a Repository to feed your View Models or Blocs etc and a separate DB Manager/Service etc.